# File extractor that its user can't change the installation path

Tags: extractor

I would like to know how I can make some kind of file extractor. But the problem is usually users could just change the target path. I wanted that it will ONLY extract the files to the location I specified.

I've seen RAR's .sfx. I've seen InstallShield. I've seen iexpress.exe.

Thank you!
Sorry if I didn't make it clear. Please ask if so.

Answer (score 0):

With [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) you can achive this with the setting:

```
[Setup]
DisableDirPage=yes
```